# How can I find the $n$'th derivative of $f(x)=x^2 \ln(x+1)$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

> > How can I find the $n$'th derivative of $f(x)=x^2 \ln(x+1)$

I have tried this

$$f(x)=x^2\ln(x+1)$$

$$ f'(x) = 2x\ln(x+1) + \frac{x^2}{x+1}$$

$$ f''(x)=2\ln(x+1) + \frac{4x}{x+1} - \frac{x^2}{(x+1)^2}$$

However I do not see any pattern :(

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Leibniz_rule

Comment: @AhmedS.Attaalla It asks for the nth derivative to be written in factorial form if that makes sense

Answer (score 5):

Taking one more derivative results in
$$
f^{(3)}(x) = \frac2{x+1} + \frac{(x+1)4-4x(1)}{(x+1)^2} - \frac{(x+1)^22x-x^22(x+1)}{(x+1)^4} = \frac{2 \left(x^2+3 x+3\right)}{(x+1)^3}.
$$
However, that's not the most convenient form for taking further derivatives: using *partial fractions* gives us
$$
f^{(3)}(x) = \frac{2}{x+1}+\frac{2}{(x+1)^2}+\frac{2}{(x+1)^3}.
$$
And this should now be easy to take as many derivatives of as you want.

Comment: I need to evaluate the function at x=0 for the 2016th derivative but I can't really see how can write an nth derivative from your expression :/

Comment: @dydxx, if you don't need a closed form for $f^{(2016)}$, only $f^{(2016)}(0)$ you can find the Taylor series of $f$ and then look at the $x^{2016}$ term.

Answer (score 1):

Taylor series gives $$f(x)=x^2\ln(1+x)=x^2\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^{n+1}\frac{x^n}{n}$$

If you want to get the 2016th derivative at x=0, it will be $$\frac{d^{2016}}{dx}((x^2)(-1)^{2014}\frac{x^{2014}}{2014})=\frac{2016!}{2014}$$

Comment: I think you forgot a negative sign. Shouldn't the 2014 be a 2015.

Answer (score 1):

Let $u=x^2$ and $v=\ln (1+x)$ then,

$$u'=2x,u''=2,u'''=0$$

And

$v^{(n)}=\frac{(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!}{(1+x)^n}$ for $n \geq 1$.

Let's compute $(uv)^{(3)}=\sum_{k=0}^{3} {3 \choose k} u^{(k)}v^{(n-k)}={3 \choose 0} x^2\frac{(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!}{(1+x)^n}+{3 \choose 1}2x\frac{(-1)^{n-2}(n-2)!}{(1+x)^{n-1}}+{3 \choose 2}2\frac{(-1)^{n-3}(n-3)!}{(1+x)^{n-2}}+{3 \choose 3}0$

With $n=3$ by the [general product rule](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/)

Now it's easy to see that for $n \geq 3$ we have

$$(uv)^{(n)}={n \choose 0} x^2\frac{(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!}{(1+x)^n}+{n \choose 1}2x\frac{(-1)^{n-2}(n-2)!}{(1+x)^{n-1}}+{n \choose 2}2\frac{(-1)^{n-3}(n-3)!}{(1+x)^{n-2}}$$

As if the third derivative of $u$ is $0$ ,and the fourth, the fifth, the sixth, etc.

This simplifies to,

$$x^2\frac{(-1)^{n-1}(n-1)!}{(1+x)^n}+2x\frac{(-1)^{n-2}n!}{(n-1)(1+x)^{n-1}}+\frac{(-1)^{n-3}n!}{(n-2)(1+x)^{n-2}}$$